# Как нарисовать такую арку через точку хорды или углы?

Tags: javascript, svg, геометрия, maker.js

Стоит следующая задача. Необходимо с использованием библиотеки [Maker.js](https://maker.js.org/) нарисовать арку такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рисование арки начинается с начала координат(`0,0`). Библиотека автоматически переворачивает изображение, так как в svg координаты начинаются от верхнего левого угла. Входные данные (вводятся пользователем):

`L` — Ширина (нижнее основание) 
`H` — Высота справа 
`H1` — Высота слева 
`R` — Радиус (Не может быть меньше `R>L/2`)

В библиотеке [Maker.js](https://maker.js.org/) создание любой фигуры делается через модели (концепция). Моя моя модель:

```js
this.model = {
  models: {
    arch: {
      paths: {
        "h1": new makerjs.paths.Line([0, 0], [0, +this.parameters.H1.value]),
        "arc": new makerjs.paths.Arc( /* Необходимо вставить параметры */ ),
        "h2": new makerjs.paths.Line([+this.parameters.L.value, +this.parameters.H.value], [+this.parameters.L.value, 0]),
        "l": new makerjs.paths.Line([+this.parameters.L.value, 0], [0, 0]),
      },
    },
  },
};
```

В Maker.js окружность можно построить 4-мя [вариантами](https://maker.js.org/docs/api/classes/makerjs.paths.arc.html). Из предложенных мне подходит построение только 2 варианта. Либо по трём точкам:

```
new Arc(pointA: IPoint, pointB: IPoint, pointC: IPoint): Arc
```

либо по двум точкам радиусу и углам:

```
new Arc(origin: IPoint, radius: number, startAngle: number, endAngle: number):
```

В первом варианте я не знаю как получить точку на хорде (отмечена красным), а во втором варианте не могу высчитать углы.

---

Вычисление точки или углов должно корректно работать на большом радиусе (например: `1000`) и при равных `H` и `H1` (`H===H1`).

Comment: а зачем красная точка? или правая и левая часть дуги имеют разную кривизну?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, одинаковые. Просто у меня нет других идей как это можно корректно отрисовать с большим радиусом.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Так же я использую `maker.js`, так как он удобно создаёт `dxf` и вот он строит дугу по трём точкам.

Comment: я сейчас напишу как построить d аттрибут

Comment: *Изначально мне дано* - а почему нам не дано?)

Comment: @РустамГимранов так мне бы формулу расчёта. Что толу если я скажу пару точек?)

Comment: Тогда вопрос "не по теме сайта" https://planetcalc.ru/1421/

Comment: @РустамГимранов так точку центра я не могу тоже найти.

Comment: А это должна быть именно дуга эллипса (окружности) или вас устроит любая кривая?

Comment: @AlexeyTen только окружность.

Comment: Судя по картинке в точке соединения с H1 касательная к окружности вертикальна?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да...

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/dqnkdsdb центр (E) лежит на точке пересечения линии проходящей через точку A параллельно L и серединного перпендикуляра к отрезку AD. Посчитать радиус должно быть несложно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99550/discussion-between-doox911-and-alexey-ten).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99576/discussion-between-doox911-and-alexey-ten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда это `R` - радиус:

```js
const makerjs = require('makerjs');

const L = 200;
const H = 200;
const H1 = 150;
const R = 150;

// Вычисение точки
function getArchCoordinate() {
  if (H === H1) {
    return {
      x: L/2,
      y: H + R - Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow(R, 2) - Math.pow(L, 2) / 4)),
    }
  } else {
    const big_hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(H - H1, 2) + Math.pow(L, 2));
    const height = R - Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow(R, 2) - Math.pow(big_hypotenuse, 2) / 4));
    return {
      x: L/2 - height*(H - H1)/big_hypotenuse,
      y: (H1 + H)/2 + height * L/big_hypotenuse,
    };
  }
}

const arch = getArchCoordinate();

const model = {
  models: {
    arch: {
      paths: {
        "line1": new makerjs.paths.Line([0, 0], [0, H1]),
        "arc": new makerjs.paths.Arc([0, H1], [arch.x, arch.y], [L, H]),
        "line2": new makerjs.paths.Line([L, H], [L, 0]),
        "line3": new makerjs.paths.Line([L, 0], [0, 0]),
      },
    },
  },
};

const svg = makerjs.exporter.toSVG(model);

document.write(svg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/makerjs@0/target/js/browser.maker.js"></script>
```

Когда `R` - высота сегмента:

```js
const makerjs = require('makerjs');

const L = 100;
const H = 200;
const H1 = 100;
const R = 30;

function getArchCoordinate() {
 
  const x = L/2 - R*(H-H1)/Math.sqrt(L*L + (H-H1)*(H-H1));
  const y = H1 + (H-H1)/2 + R*L/Math.sqrt(L*L + (H-H1)*(H-H1));

  console.log('x', x);
  console.log('y', y);
  
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
  };
    
}

const arch = getArchCoordinate();

const model = {
  models: {
    arch: {
      paths: {
        "line1": new makerjs.paths.Line([0, 0], [0, H1]),
        "arc": new makerjs.paths.Arc([0, H1], [arch.x, arch.y], [L, H]),
        "line2": new makerjs.paths.Line([L, H], [L, 0]),
        "line3": new makerjs.paths.Line([L, 0], [0, 0]),
      },
    },
  },
};

const svg = makerjs.exporter.toSVG(model);

document.write(svg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/makerjs@0/target/js/browser.maker.js"></script>
```

> UPD Подробное описание и варианты нахождения искомой точки описано [тут](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380672/how-to-find-mid-point-of-a-slant-arc) и [тут](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404609/how-to-find-midpoint-on-an-arc-across-uneven-heights/3406208#3406208).

Answer (score 3):

Советую научиться в голове строить пути, на самом деле это очень поросто, в этом конкретном случае это легче если комбинировать абсолютные и относительные комманды.

Мы начинаем в точке 0;0 - команда `m0,0`

двигаемся вниз на H1 - команда `v${H1}`

затем вправо на L - `h${L}`

вверх на H - `v${-H}`

а теперь маленький лайфхак - больше не надо ничего считать - конечная точка дуги - начало координат - тоесть осталось начертить дугу необходимого радиуса абсолютной командой в точку 0;0 - `A${R},${R},0,0,0,0,0`

```js
let H = 60, H1 = 40, L = 40, R = 23.5;

path.setAttribute("d", `m0,0v${H1}h${L}v${-H}A${R},${R},0,0,0,0,0z`)
```

```html
<svg viewbox=-100,-100,200,200><path id=path fill=none stroke=black></path></svg>
```

Comment: Абсолютно не то что должно получится). Дуга должна прижиматься к линии `H1` `H`

Comment: @doox911 а этого нет в вопросе, и я не понял что куда должно прижиматься

Comment: так по этому и вопрос создал) Важно рассчитать третью точку) Т. е. центр окружности выходит за рамки фигуры.

Comment: @doox911 я не понял что куда должно прижиматься, что за линия H1 H? больше никаких метрик в вопросе не указано.

Comment: Это наклонная линия, к которой опущен перпендикуляр `R`

Comment: На вопрос "Как нарисовать такую арку" при заданных условиях этот ответ полностью отвечает. Точку красную найти можно, но действительно ли это нужно?

Comment: @doox911 все равно не понятно...

Comment: Ваш пример работает, но как поставить ограничение, чтобы дуга не выходила за линию H1? И хотелось бы, строить через три точки.

Comment: @doox911 увеличьте радиус, через 3 точки будет - уже нужно голову включать и считать точку

Comment: @doox911 и кстати да - на картинке - не радиус указан, значит то что я нарисовал не верно

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а идеи есть как сделать)?

Comment: `чтобы дуга не выходила за линию H1?` Если радиус задан, то этого гарантировать нельзя.